# Compare each multidimensional array value to all values in second multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

Im a bit new here, Thanks for the help in advance.

I got 2 Multidimensional Arrays in PHP

Both pretty much look like this one:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [Id] => 1
            [1] => Soldier
            [Name] => Soldier
            [2] => 100
            [Hitpoints] => 100
            [3] => 15
            [Attack] => 15
            [4] => 50
            [Speed] => 50
            [5] => 50
            [Range] => 50
            [Total Units] => 511
            [Combined Damage] => 7588.35
            [Combined Hitpoints] => 51100
            [Position] => 50
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [Id] => 2
            [1] => Sniper
            [Name] => Sniper
            [2] => 20
            [Hitpoints] => 20
            [3] => 50
            [Attack] => 50
            [4] => 20
            [Speed] => 20
            [5] => 300
            [Range] => 0
            [Total Units] => 0
            [Combined Damage] => 0
            [Combined Hitpoints] => 0
            [Position] => 50
        )

)
```

The arrays names are:

$Attackers

$Defenders

I need to compare values from `$Attackers[*]['Position'] with $Defenders[*]['Position']`.

I did make this loop but my problem is, that it only checks the same Index count to eachother. I need to check the $Attackers[0] to all $Defender indexes, then $Attackers[1] to all $Defender indexes, and so on.

Heres my original code that works, but only checks against the same index.

```
 for($rowcount=0;$rowcount<count($Attackers);$rowcount++){
            if (isset($Attackers[$rowcount]['Range']) && $Attackers[$rowcount]['Range'] != 0) {
                if (($Attackers[$rowcount]['Position'] + $Defenders[$rowcount]['Position']) < $Attackers[$rowcount]['Range']) {
                    echo "within range, ATTACK";
                } else {
                    echo "Before: " . $Attackers[$rowcount]['Position'] . "<br>";
                    $Attackers[$rowcount]['Position'] = $Attackers[$rowcount]['Position'] - $Attackers[$rowcount]['Speed'];
                    echo "After: " . $Attackers[$rowcount]['Position'] . "<br>";
                }
            }
        }
```

I hope this is enough information.
Regards
Jesper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use nested for loops to check all the defenders positions versus one attackers position.

Something like this should get you started.

```
for($rowcount=0;$rowcount<count($Attackers);$rowcount++){
    for($defrowcount=0; $defrowcount<count($Defenders); $defrowcount++){
                   if (isset($Attackers[$rowcount]['Range']) && $Attackers[$rowcount]['Range'] != 0) {
            if (($Attackers[$rowcount]['Position'] + $Defenders[$defrowcount]['Position']) < $Attackers[$rowcount]['Range']) {
                echo "within range, ATTACK";
            } else {
                echo "Before: " . $Attackers[$rowcount]['Position'] . "<br>";
                $Attackers[$rowcount]['Position'] = $Attackers[$rowcount]['Position'] - $Attackers[$rowcount]['Speed'];
                echo "After: " . $Attackers[$rowcount]['Position'] . "<br>";
            }
        }
     }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, i ended up using your example. Even thou this is not the optimized way, this is what i need. Only been 2 months in PHP, so getting into OOP already is way to early, and i think that by doing it the slow way, i can easier see where i can improve myself and learn from that.

Comment: I'm terrible at optimizing code when just looking at it.  Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this kind of check is pretty horrific and not scalable...

You would possibly benefit from having a map of positions. You could then simplify by observing events and applying outcomes.

```
class GameMap implements SplObserver
{
    private $positions;

    public function __construct($xSize, $ySize)
    {
        $this->positions = array();
        for ($x = 0; $x < $xSize; $x++) {
            $this->positions[$x] = array();
            for ($y = 0; $y < $ySize; $y++) {
                $this->positions[$x][$y] = new MapPosition($x, $y);
            }
        }
    }

    public function update(SplSubject $subject)
    {
        switch ($subject->getAction($this)) {
            case "attack":
                $positions = $this->getPositionsInRange($subject);
                foreach ($positions as $position) {
                    $position->defend($subject);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private function getPositionsInRange(Soldier $soldier)
    {
        $inRange = array();
        $position = $soldier->getPosition();
        $range = $soldier->range;

        for ($x = ($position->coord["x"] - $range); $x < ($position->coord["x"] + $range); $x++) {
            for ($y = ($position->coord["y"] - $range); $y < ($position->coord["y"] + $range); $y++) {
                if (isset($this->positions[$x][$y])) {
                    $inRange[] = $this->positions[$x][$y];
                }
            }
        }
        return $inRange;
    }

    public function __get($key)
    {
        return isset($this->$key) ? $this->$key : null;
    }
}

class MapPosition
{
    private $coords = array();
    private $players;

    public function __construct($x, $y)
    {
        $this->coords["x"] = $x;
        $this->coords["y"] = $y;
        $this->players = new SplObjectStorage();
    }

    public function enter(Soldier $player)
    {
        $this->players->attach($player);
        return $this;
    }

    public function leave(Soldier $player)
    {
        $this->players->detach($player);
        return $this;
    }

    public function defend(Soldier $soldier)
    {
        foreach($this->players as $player)
        {
            $player->defend($soldier);
        }
    }

    public function __get($key)
    {
        return isset($this->$key) ? $this->$key : null;
    }
}

class Soldier implements SplSubject
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $hitPoints;
    private $health;
    private $attack;
    private $speed;
    private $range;

    private $observers;
    private $action;
    private $position;

    public function __construct($soldierData)
    {
        $this->id = $soldierData["id"];
        $this->name = $soldierData["name"];
        $this->hitPoints = $soldierData["hit_points"];
        $this->health = $soldierData["health"];
        $this->attack = $soldierData["attack"];
        $this->speed = $soldierData["speed"];
        $this->range = $soldierData["range"];

        $this->observers = new SplObjectStorage();
    }

    public function attach(SplObserver $observer)
    {
        $this->observers->attach($observer);
    }

    public function detach(SplObserver $observer)
    {
        $this->observers->detach($observer);
    }

    public function notify()
    {
        foreach ($this->observers as $observer) {
            $observer->update($this);
        }
    }

    public function getAction($observer)
    {
        return $this->observers->contains($observer) ? $this->action : null;
    }

    public function setPosition(MapPosition $position)
    {
        $this->postion = $position;
    }

    public function getPosition()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    public function attack()
    {
        $this->action = "attack";
        $this->notify();
    }

    public function defend(Soldier $soldier)
    {
        $this->health -= $soldier->attack;
    }

    public function __get($key)
    {
        return isset($this->$key) ? $this->$key : null;
    }
}

$s1 = new Soldier(array(
    "id" => 1,
    "name" => 'Sniper',
    "hit_points" => 1000,
    "health" => 100,
    "attack" => 20,
    "speed" => 5,
    "range" => 10
));

$s2 = new Soldier(array(
    "id" => 1,
    "name" => 'Medic',
    "hit_points" => 10000,
    "health" => 100,
    "attack" => 4,
    "speed" => 10,
    "range" => 1
));

$s3 = new Soldier(array(
    "id" => 1,
    "name" => 'Private',
    "hit_points" => 5000,
    "health" => 100,
    "attack" => 10,
    "speed" => 15,
    "range" => 3
));

$a1 = new Soldier(array(
    "id" => 1,
    "name" => 'Sniper',
    "hit_points" => 1000,
    "health" => 100,
    "attack" => 20,
    "speed" => 5,
    "range" => 15
));

$a2 = new Soldier(array(
    "id" => 1,
    "name" => 'Medic',
    "hit_points" => 10000,
    "health" => 100,
    "attack" => 4,
    "speed" => 10,
    "range" => 1
));

$a3 = new Soldier(array(
    "id" => 1,
    "name" => 'Private',
    "hit_points" => 5000,
    "health" => 100,
    "attack" => 10,
    "speed" => 15,
    "range" => 3
));

$map = new GameMap(20, 20);
$s1->attach($map);
$s2->attach($map);
$s3->attach($map);
$a1->attach($map);
$a2->attach($map);
$a3->attach($map);

$map->positions[0][0]->enter($a1)->enter($a2)->enter($a3);
$map->positions[9][9]->enter($s1)->enter($s2)->enter($s3);

var_dump($s1->health, $s2->health, $s3->health);

$a1->attack();

var_dump($s1->health, $s2->health, $s3->health);

$map->positions[9][9]->leave($s3);
$map->positions[19][19]->enter($s3);

$a1->attack();

var_dump($s1->health, $s2->health, $s3->health);
```

There is lots and lots of room for improvement here but hopefully you can see that you don't need to do all this checking. A soldier can attack, the attack notifies the map and the map checks which positions are in range of the attack. The positions then call the defend method of any soldiers in that position. The soldier defending then has their health reduced by the attack amount.

As I said LOADS of room for improvement like introducing sides and making sure no friendly fire kills can happen. Improve movement by applying move methods to Soldiers and they could then trigger leave/enter events on MapPositions (making the MapPosition an observer of the soldier too perhaps).

The main point though is that this looping is not really necessary and would suffer in scaling. Better design of your app will reap its own rewards...

Comment: You method seems very complex, but i can see the benefits of a system like that. However that is way over my skills, and i wouldnt know where to begin. I have used thomasw_lrd answer, but im not sure which to click Answered on. Doest it have to be the correct way i accept, or just the one i pick?

Comment: click the one you go with but I would advise that if this is a project that has a decent life expectancy you'll be better served looking at a solution with more flexibility. This only LOOKS more complex - once you get into it its actually really simple.

Comment: Thanks Ian, i will defitnally bookmark your solution, so i can learn from it later :)